# Не удается авторизоваться на сайте Ucoz C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser, awesomium

Здравствуйте. Используя компонент webbrowser  в C# проходил авторизацию на сайте от Ucoz через их общий аккаунт Uid. На ноутбуке все работает (там виндовс 7 стоит и писалась программа на нем же), а на домашнем пк (вин 10) нет, страница обновляется, но авторизация не происходит.
Решил попробовать сделать то же самое через awesomium, но результат почти тот же. Все отличие только в том, что здесь после клика по иконке авторизации через uid, вк или что-то еще вообще ничего не происходит, даже обновления страницы...
Может чего-то не хватает?
У меня VS 2015

Кода для авторизации никакого нет. В свойствах компонента адрес указал и все.
По крайне мере, весь имеющийся код никак не относится к авторизации.

Comment: Код-то покажите, которым не получается. Как иначе мы можем воспроизвести и решить вашу проблему?

Comment: А какой может быть код? Все делается руками. Разместил компонент на форме, в настройках указал адрес, который надо загружать, и все.